# Android Studio not changing API version

Tags: android-studio

Whenever I go and try to click to change the API version, it stays the same and will not switch to the one I choose. Do I need to add something for it to change?

Here is a picture of my IDE:

[image]

As you can see, it is on API 15.

I have several different API's listed but it will not change to them if I click on one.

Comment: do you have those API levels' SDK installed?

Comment: Yes they are installed.

Comment: its due to rendering problems.

Answer (score 0):

There is two different api, first one is Viewing api, it's shows on editing xml, in this case it's shown as your photo. Second one is real one. Its building api. You can reach them from "Gradle" -> "Build Gradle". There is 2 different API's min sdk and target sdk. You can change api from there. And don't forget to sync your Gradle